# Use powershell to set LDAP MaxConnIdleTime

Tags: powershell, ldap, windows-server-2016

I need a scripted solution (preferrably powershell) to modify the LDAP parameter called MaxConnIdleTime on Server 2016.  I found that there is a command line executable called ntdsutil.exe, however, using ntdsutil to set the MaxConnIdleTime requires launching the program, and entering sub-menus to change the setting:

At the "ntdsutil:" prompt, enter "LDAP policies", At the "ldap policy:" prompt, enter "connections"
, At the "server connections:" prompt, enter "connect to server [host-name]" (where [host-name] is the computer name of the domain controller), At the "server connections:" prompt, enter "q", At the "ldap policy:" prompt, enter "Set MaxConnIdleTime to [new value]", Enter "Commit Changes" to save

Is it possible to script passing multiple commands to ntdsutil in sequence, or skip ntdsutil and modify the setting another way with powershell?  I couldn't find any powershell cmdlets with this level of control over LDAP settings.

Comment: I found an example in VB, so definitely doable in PS. Probably use Get-ADObject to get your ldapAdminLimits, then looping through to set the 
 MaxConnIdleTime. [VB_Example](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/active-directory-cookbook/0596004648/ch04s24.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found that multiple commands can be sent to ntdsutil in sequence.  From powershell it is a one-line solution.  To run this from a batch file, just remove the &.

```
& ntdsutil "LDAP policies" connections "connect to server [serverName]" quit "Set MaxConnIdleTime to [timeInSeconds]" "Commit Changes" quit quit
```

the key to solving this was the documentation at:
https://ss64.com/nt/ntdsutil.html